# How to separate one column's data into multiple columns?

Tags: ms-access

Here's my situation : I have a table that has large amounts of records, I need to pull out a number of these records for each name in the database, note that TOP will not work for my use case. My end user wants the report formatted in such a way that each user shows up only once, and up to 3 different dates are shown for the user.

Table format

| AutoID | Enum | TNum | Date | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 18 | 2/2/22 |  |
| 2 | 25 | 18 | 1/2/21 | Blah |
| 3 | 18 | 18 | 1/2/21 |  |
| 4 | 18 | 18 | 1/2/20 |  |
| 5 | 25 | 17 | 1/2/22 |  |
| 6 | 25 | 17 | 1/2/20 |  |

Now the Enum and TNum fields are fk with other tables, I have created a join that pulls the correct information from the other tables. In the end my query provides this output

| RecordID | Training | CompletedDate |  |  | FirstName | LastName | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2821 | MaP | 1/1/21 |  |  | David | Simpson | 123 Sesame St. | 2822 | 1/2/22 |  | Fuller |  | MaP |  |  | Dough |  | GHI |  | David | 123 Sesame St. | 2825 | 1/1/20 |  | Simpson |

The two "Blank fields" represent information that is pulled and may or may not be needed in some future report.

So to my question : How do I manage to get a report, with this query's pull to look like this:

| Place | LastName | FirstName | Training | FirstCuttoff | Secondcutoff | ThirdCutoff | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 Sesame St. | David | Simpson | MaP | 1/1/20 | 1/1/21 |  |  |
| 123 Sesame St. | John | Dough | MaP |  |  | 1/1/22 |  |

I was originally planning on joining my query to itself using where clauses. But when I tried that it just added two extra columns of the same date. In addition it is possible that each record is not identical; locations may be different but since the report needs the most recent location and the name of the trainee. In addition, to add more complexity, there are a number of people in the company with effectively the same name as far as the database is concerned, so rejoining on the name is out. I did pull the Enum in my query, I can join on that if needed.

Is there an easier way to do this, or do I need to sort out a multiple self-joining query?

Answer (score 0):

I have a project I am working on where I am going to have to do this. Some of the suggestions I received were to use a Pivot query. It wouldn't work in my case but it might for yours. Here is a good example

[Pivot Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/pivot-columns#:%7E:text=1%20Pivot%20columns.%202%20Select%20the%20column%20that,box%2C%20in%20the%20Value%20column%20list%2C%20select%20Value.)

Comment: Yeah That wouldn't work for my use case either, I had already thought of that. But it would make dates my column names, and I need dates in the data field, besides if it did work I could potentially have a table more than 1000 columns wide. Not a problem for access to handle, but still.